# how to build a 64 bit project in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

In my visual studio 2010 ultimate, codes in `#if _WIN64` region is always dark. I selected X64 platform in my configuration manager. What do I do to compile a 64 bit project?

Comment: Just solved. I found that I need to add _WIN64 in the preprocessor.

Comment: See also "Seven Steps of Migrating a Program to a 64-bit System" - http://www.viva64.com/en/a/0042/