# Build an x64 DLL with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to build my dll file as x64, here are the configurations I have done on VisualStudio:

- I have set solution and project platform to x64:

[image: 3]

- According [to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28062677/7784017), I have changed naming convention from __cdecl to __fastcall:

[image: 1]

- According [to this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862945/how-to-build-a-64-bit-project-in-visual-studio?noredirect=1#comment27835138_18862945) I have added the argument _WIN64 to Preprocessor Definitions:

[image: 2]

But still, when I rebuild my project and open my dll file using notepad, I see `PE L` [which means](https://superuser.com/a/889267/856975) my dll file is 32 bit.

Here's the command line options of the C/C++ settings (for better reading, I put a couple of line breaks in there):

```
/JMC /permissive- /GS /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm- /Od /sdl 
/Fd"x64\Debug\vc142.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_WIN64" /D "_DEBUG" /D 
"_CONSOLE" /D "_WINDLL" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- 
/Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gr /MDd /FC /Fa"x64\Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Debug\" 
/Fp"x64\Debug\DllCall-CppConsoleApp-1.pch" /diagnostics:column
```

- Linker settings:

[image: 4]

[image: 5]

What should I do?

Comment: From [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/fastcall?view=vs-2019): "_The `__fastcall` calling convention specifies that arguments to functions are to be passed in registers, when possible. This calling convention only applies to the x86 architecture._" - so it seems wrong here.

Comment: Oh I see, but even with `__cdecl` I still get a 32 bit dll.

Comment: The calling convention doesn't change the bitness of the DLL anyway. There is a deeper problem. For completeness, can you show the whole command line that was generated from the settings? And show the Linker > Advanced settings

Comment: Updated again with Linker settings @harold

Comment: I get `PE  d†` without making any changes to the project settings (except compiling for x64) or defining `_WIN64` manually.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Have you set `Configuration Type` to `DLL` and `Target File Extension` to `DLL` like me?

Comment: I can copy paste my `.vcxproj` file as well if that helps to find the issue.

Comment: I just created a new DLL project, set it to x64 and added a few functions and compiled. No other changes. It got the `Configuration Type` and `Target File Extension` set to `.dll` automatically.

Comment: This is a console app project, not a dll project, later I decided I want it to be dll and changed the Config Type and Target File Extension

Comment: It's perhaps easier to create a new project as a DLL project and just copy the old code into that project. If it works, you can diff the project files to find out what caused the problem.

Comment: Check to make sure your settings are actually being applied to the active project. The images all show Platform: x64. It should show (Active) x64. Your "Active" Platform may well be x86.

Comment: @Shayan `later I decided I want it to be dll` You still have `/D_CONSOLE` which conflicts with `/D_WINDLL`. Compare to a wizard-generated DLL project to see what else you've got wrong. `open my dll file using notepad` You have VS installed, so use [dumpbin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference?view=vs-2019) to examine the DLL, not notepad.